# How do I increase content area width of my blog on blogger?

Tags: blogger

i am using free version of classic chalkboard template for blogger-https://gooyaabitemplates.com/classic-chalkboard-blogger-template/

I tried almost every tutorial on width increase like search for code “#main-wrapper’’ but i dint found this code in my template. please help

Comment: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/176245?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for

```
.wrapper
```

and

```
#pagebwrap
```

and increase the max-width of those values and this should increase the content area width.